# Created performance counters not visible

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I have to create performance counters programmaticaly. Seems that code is working but I don't see performance counters category in perfmon. When I mean that code is working I'm saying that it doesn't throw any exceptions. I am running it as administrator.

I've seen answers on SO saying that it may take some time for counters to appear. But I installed them before going home and next day they are still not visible.

Here is a little console app to test it. I install counters, then work with them but can't see them in performance monitor.

Edit: I tested it on 3 machines, and it works on one of them as expected (perf counters visible in perfmon). Is it possible to see performance counters somewhere else in windows (Powershell, some sysinternals tool?)

`using System;
using System.Diagnostics;`

namespace PerfCounters
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var program = new Program();
            program.Run();
        }

```
    private const string CATEGORY_NAME = "AAAMySpecialCategory";
    private const string CATEGORY_HELP = "AAAMySpecialCategory Help";
    private const string OPS_IN_CURRENT_COUNTER_NAME = "# current calls";

    public void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            PrintUsage();
            Console.Write(":> ");
            var keyInfo = Console.ReadLine();
            if (keyInfo == "q")
            {
                break;
            }

            switch (keyInfo)
            {
                case "i":
                    InstallPerfCountersCategory();
                    break;

                case "c":
                    Console.WriteLine(PerformanceCounterCategoryExists()
                            ? "Perf counter category ({0}) does exist"
                            : "Perf counter categry ({0}) does not exist", CATEGORY_NAME);
                    break;

                case "w":
                    IncrementPerfCounter();
                    break;

                case "u":
                    UninstallPerfCountersCategory();
                    break;
            }
        } 
    }

    private static void PrintUsage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Usage:");
        Console.WriteLine("i - install performance counters category ({0})", CATEGORY_NAME);
        Console.WriteLine("c - check if category exists ({0})", CATEGORY_NAME);
        Console.WriteLine("w - work with perf counter (increment)");
        Console.WriteLine("u - uninstall performance counters category ({0})", CATEGORY_NAME);
        Console.WriteLine("q - quit");
    }
    private void IncrementPerfCounter()
    {
        if (!PerformanceCounterCategoryExists())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Perf counter category ({0}) does not exist - install first", CATEGORY_NAME);
            return;
        }

        var currentOps = new PerformanceCounter(CATEGORY_NAME, OPS_IN_CURRENT_COUNTER_NAME, false);
        Console.Write("Incrementing perf counter");
        currentOps.Increment();
        Console.WriteLine(" - incremented");
    }
    private void InstallPerfCountersCategory()
    {
        if (PerformanceCounterCategoryExists())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Uninstall first");
            return;
        }

        var ccdc = new CounterCreationDataCollection
        {
            new CounterCreationData(OPS_IN_CURRENT_COUNTER_NAME, "", PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems32),
        };

        PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(CATEGORY_NAME, CATEGORY_HELP, PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, ccdc);
        Console.WriteLine("Installed");
    }
    private void UninstallPerfCountersCategory()
    {
        if (PerformanceCounterCategoryExists())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Deleting perf counter category ({0})", CATEGORY_NAME);
            PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete(CATEGORY_NAME);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Perf counter category ({0}) does not exist - install first", CATEGORY_NAME);
        }
    }
    private bool PerformanceCounterCategoryExists()
    {
        return PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(CATEGORY_NAME);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are all the machines you tested it on running the same operating system?

Comment: Yes. All of them run Windows7 64 bit. I also ran my installer on win2003 and category appeared in performance monitor.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue - .NET code reported that the counters were there, but there were no such counter categories visible in perfmon.

Apparently perfmon will sometimes [disable performance counters by flagging it as disabled in the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341079/windows-performance-counters-disappearing-from-perfmon#11801008).

If you [check in the registry](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/248993) under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services` you should be able to find your performance counter category (just look for the your category name as one of the "folders").  Under the subkey ("folder") `Performance` find the registry value `Disable Performance Counters` and set it to zero.  Restart perfmon and you should now see your categories and counters in perfmon.